# Place Button just after end of TextView in multilline TextView?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, textview, android-button

I'm developing an Android application that contains some text view and button.

I need to put Button just after the text view. When my TextView is single line that's working well. But when using multiple line of text view , my button was placed to the end of line 1.

How to place button in the right position (after last line in the text view)?

after edit :
this is my xml , I use it in my code and generate it dynamically .

```
<TableLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:shrinkColumns="1"
android:stretchColumns="1"  >

   <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/ayehPlace_btnCounter"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ayeh_counter"
    android:text="" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ayehPlace_txtAyeh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ayehPlace_txt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" /> 
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: try using android:baselineAligned=""

Comment: put your layout code or show some rough sketch of it.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `android:gravity="bottom"` on your (presumably) horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Do you want your `Button` right below the `TextView`?

Comment: no , I want it to place beside the end character of my textview

Comment: I think so you need, is use a RelativeLayout, no a TableLayout, with that you can put relative to your TextView the Button. Can you put some picture for see what do you want exactly? and then post for your an xml using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use Table Layout instead .... It worked for me ..

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""/>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Fix the android:layout_width to some numeric value .. for ex
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:lines="5"

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and add

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewid"
```

to Button.

Comment: I do that but the button was placed to end of the line one of text view horizontally , so that's not work

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer to use table layout instead..it makes the UI uniform and adjusts automatically

```
<TableLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:shrinkColumns="1"
       android:stretchColumns="1" >

       <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Main Status             "
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/retentionMainStatus"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="CLICK ME" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: that's still not work , the button place end of the line one horizontally

Comment: I post it on my question , tanks for your atention

Comment: Your XML shows that u have the button before the text view and what you wanna do is button after the textview ...how would that be possible...
copy paste the xml mentioned above where the textview is before the button

Comment: fix the value of android:layout_width="100dp"

Comment: Well I use right of gravity for my layout so if put button after textView that's not work . I really confused ... I think because of the textview width is constant for all lines , my button take wrong position . I mean because of this , it take end of line one X . so how could find end of last line position ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to use TableLayout together with android:gravity="bottom". Try it.