# how could find out the end of text position in textview?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, textview, android-button

after asking a question about [Place Button just after end of TextView in multilline TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290001/place-button-just-after-end-of-textview-in-multilline-textview)
I give no answer but I think if find the position of end character of final line of textview , then my problem is solved .
so how could find out the end of text position in last line of textview?
tank's for your help and your attention.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630086/how-to-get-string-width-on-android

Comment: I want the last line rect . how could do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence cs = textView.getText();
int position = cs.charAt(cs.length()-1);
```

Comment: Tank's , but the position represent what?

Comment: The index of the last character. I would use it to hack in a link.

Comment: so is there a way to find it's position(X,Y)?

Comment: Obtusely with [this](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/awt/Component/getLocationOnScreen%28%29.html). If you are going to just throw a button in, do it in the xml with a relative layout.

Comment: It does not work because the textview width is constant for all lines and that's equal to line one width's . I need find the position of end character of my textview , with that component how could do this ?  thanks for your attention